# How to do a Customer Logger for Django to Capture Response and Request

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm looking into differen't ways to capture the response object, request object, and performance in Django to create a custom json elk logger that will build audit logs.

I'm not sure what approach is best to take here. I was looking at custom middleware but I've never done that.

I tried to look up if it was possible to use a decorator to do this but doesn't seem like it.

Also, I use the django rest framework so I also have to figure out how to integrate the middleware if thats the route or whatever solution to DRF as well.

Looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you use DRF, i advice you pckage - [drf-tracking](https://github.com/aschn/drf-tracking). Just add mixin LoggingMixin to you class like this:

```
class ProbeView(LoggingMixin, APIView):
    ...
```

And after this, each qyery for this view wiil be logged in database. Example:
[image]